# How can i change App background color as mentioned (Red marker) in screen shot in react native?

Tags: react-native

[image: I want to change red marker's BG color]

I want to change red marker's BG color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [StatusBar](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbarhttps://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbar) component for that

Comment: Thanks!!.. I m new to react native.

Comment: glad to help.!!